# Threejs flat helical shape

Tags: three.js

I am looking at creating a helical shape and would like some guidance on the approach.  Imagine you wrapped a flat ribbon around a cylindrical tube (with a space between each turn), that Is the shape I am trying to create.

my initial thought was to use the tube geometry, but that seems to only be able to accept a circular profile.  I would like a flat/straight profile

Since I will eventually also want a shape at the end of the helix, I thought about creating a couple of arrays of points, one for the outer helix, the other for the inner helix then use the three shape, but I believe that can only do 2D shapes, which this wont be.

Whilst defining a cylinder would be very confinient, just putting a texture on it wont give me the control I require

The maths behind a helix aren't difficult, I just don't know the best approach in ThreeeJS to actually create it?  Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also just noting that questions like this could generate opinionated answers (discussing approaches is more prone to opinions than a straightforward question with a valid answer, even if there are several valid answers). If this question is meant to be a brainstorming/hypothetical conversation, it would find a better home here: https://discourse.threejs.org/

Comment: thanks @TheJim01 i will post the question there instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone is interested I did get a decent repsonse with a good approach from the three discourse page..

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/creating-a-helical-sweep-with-a-flat-profile/3163/2

All credit to "prisoner849" from that forum, heres a direct link to a code pen with his answer which involved bending a thin box

https://jsfiddle.net/5Lycd4rm/7/

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 3, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x101000);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.setScalar(100);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

var rbnWidth = .5;
var rbnThickness = 0.1;
var rbnSteps = 1;
var rbnStepLength = 1.5;
var rbnSegsPerStep = 50;
var rbnRadius = 1;

var rbnGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(rbnSteps * Math.PI * 2, rbnWidth, rbnThickness, rbnSteps * rbnSegsPerStep, 1, 1);
rbnGeom.computeBoundingBox();
var size = new THREE.Vector3();
rbnGeom.boundingBox.getSize(size);
rbnGeom.translate(size.x * 0.5, size.y * 0.5, size.z * 0.5);

// bend it!

rbnGeom.vertices.forEach(v => {
  let angle = -v.x;
  let radius = rbnRadius + v.z;
  let shift = (v.x / (Math.PI * 2)) * rbnStepLength + v.y;

  v.x = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
  v.y = shift;
  v.z = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
}); 

rbnGeom.computeFaceNormals();
rbnGeom.computeVertexNormals();

rbnGeom.center();


var ribbon = new THREE.Mesh(rbnGeom, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0x0099ff}));
scene.add(ribbon);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```